# rosbag keyboard controls unresponsive

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have been using `rosbag play` to test some CPU-intensive computer vision algorithms on recorded data. Periodically during playback the command-line interface to `rosbag play` becomes completely unresponsive: the timer stops counting and it is no longer responsive to keyboard controls. Messages are still being published while it is unresponsive (verified with `rostopic hz` and `image_view`). If I play the same data back without the CPU-intensive nodes running, everything is fine.

Stepping through the data is important for evaluating my nodes, so this has been very frustrating. Has anyone found a workaround for this problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10090/rosbag-keyboard-controls-unresponsive/) by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on ROS Answers with karma: 524 on 2011-05-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [phil0stine](https://answers.ros.org/users/639/phil0stine/) on 2012-01-25**:
Im getting the same behavior, but I have noticed that (for me at least), /clock is no longer being published, even though the actual data messages are. Since /clock is so important, I am a bit surprised at this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I will offer some observations I made when I was playing back and processing bags with Kinect data, which may or may not fix your issue.

First, try tweaking the `--rate` and `--queue` [parameters](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosbag/Commandline).

Second, try loading the bag using `rxbag`, and playing it from there, instead of the command line. Using `rxbag`, I was able to get better system performance than `rosbag play`. Also I think it gives you better control over the playback - like starting at specific times or stepping through frame by frame.

Hope this helps,

Ivan

---

Originally posted by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) with karma: 4954 on 2011-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mkoval](https://answers.ros.org/users/309/mkoval/) on 2011-05-28**:
Using the --rate options with a fractional rate fixed the problem. Thanks!